# How to get Dynamic Search Results : Python / Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am new to Python , Selenium and need some help on how to do this:

I am searching for certain things on a site and after searching, the results that are rendered are dynamic based on the search. I am trying to get the results set , but unable to on how to do it:
Here's a part of the results page that the code has and I am trying to get all the listings. I specifically want to iterate through each listing and also want to get each listing code (1111111111 , 1111111112....)

```
 <div id="listingsParent">
        <div id="listings" class="visibleLayer">
        <div>
          <div id="listing_1111111111">
            <div class="abc test">.......</div>
            ----
            ----
         </div>
          <div id="listing_1111111112">
            <div class="abc test1">.......</div>
            ----
            ----
         </div>
          <div id="listing_1111111113">
            <div class="abc test2">.......</div>
            ----
            ----
         </div>
          <div id="listing_1111111114">
            <div class="abc test3">.......</div>
            ----
            ----
         </div>
```

I have used the code:

allListings = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='listings']")
LisBegin = allListings.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(text(), 'listing_']")

and then trying to get the attribute "id" .....listing_1111111111
which is not working for me.

Thank You for your help

Raj

Answer (score 0):

You can achief this via xpath, all the elements that have a id that contain `listing_` will match this xpath

```
LisBegin = allListings.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@id, 'listing_')]")
```

You can look at [this](http://www.guru99.com/xpath-selenium.html) for more information of xpath.

Also have a look at [locators in selenium](https://www.protechtraining.com/bookshelf/selenium_tutorial/locators?ncr=1) for more information about the different locators

I hope this will help you in your work, if you have any questions, don't hesitate to ask them.

Answer (score 0):

**Observation 1 :** It has to be findelement and not findelements.

```
allListings = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='listings']")
```

**Observation 2 :** use id instead of text.

```
LisBegin = allListings.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@id, 'listing_')]")
```

Hope this helps you. Thanks.

Comment: Thank You... Once I get the "LisBegin" , what should i need to use to fetch the value '1111111111'

Comment: Now LisBegin contains all the listing_****** nodes.. For  getting the displayed text.. In java we use getText. String value = LisBegin.get(0).getText();